# Is twilio-common.js from github the same as twilio-client.js from their CDN?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I am implementing the Twilio SDK client via the twilio CDN:
//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.4/twilio.min.js

However I am looking to pull the package in via npm (due to certain restrictions).  However I am only seeing:
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-common.js

As a package.  If I use twilio-common, am I missing functionality provided via their CDN SDK?  If so, is that functionality documented?

I assume video is part of https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js, but nothing is very clear in the docs that I have found.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

twilio-common.js is a library that twilio-video, twilio-sync and twilio-chat can use for access token management and is not related to Twilio Client at all.

Twilio Client is available on npm as the [`twilio-client` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-client).

Just save it to your dependencies with

```
npm install twilio-client --save
```

Comment: Super lame!  I was really hoping to avoid that as our policies do not allow for 3rd party CDNs but i guess I have no choice.

Comment: I'm told that it is available on npm, but I can't find it. The latest version is also broken, so I'm waiting for the package name and an update, but I will let you know.

Comment: Ok, the package is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-client though apparently 1.4.28 is broken right now. Try an earlier version or wait for 1.4.29 to be released later today or tomorrow.

Comment: It looks like 1.4.29 is available now.  Thanks @philnash